# Publish Zip Package from VSTS to Octopus Deploy

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to deploy an artifact from VSTS to an Azure App Service, using Deploy an Azure Web App step template in Octopus Deploy. The VSTS zip package will have a structure like the following:
`\Content\C_C\a\1\s\Api{ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp`

When I publish the zip file using `MsDeploy.exe`. It automatically only copy the folders & files inside the `PackageTmp` folder into the `wwwroot` folder. However, when I use the Octopus deploy, It copies all of the folder from `Content\`. Is there any way to make the Octopus deploy work like using MsDeploy.exe? I'd like to use the zip as is, so adding a `Copy Files` step or changing the `PackageLocation` in the VSTS build is not really an option.

Any help/suggestion is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the layout of the files as you describe, you will have to modify your build step. In the MSBuild arguments section on the build step, ensure you have the following parameters defined:
`/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem` `/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

These two parameters will create the package in the directory specified by the PackageLocation parameter, and it should be in the format you expect.
In the step where you push the package to Octopus specify this directory as the Package Source.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t such setting to do it.

You can publish the web app with **File System** mode , then package the files through [Package Application](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/tfs-vsts/using-octopus-extension#UsetheTeamFoundationBuildCustomTask-AddStepstoyourBuildorReleaseProcess-packageUsingExtension) task.